# VB Script For Confirm close window

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a vbscript which prompt a close confirmation window when i click on close button/ALT + F4 of a particular application, Let the application be Notepad.exe.

Can anyone help me please :(

Thanks and regards

Ajin

Comment: You're going to have a hard time accomplishing this in any language, let alone VBScript. What about `File->Exit`? Or right-click on the taskbar button and `Close`? There are a number of ways to close an app.

Comment: Here what i am facing is in windows 7, i replaced explorer.exe with an application eg: notepad.exe , so here what happens is when user log in he/she will be able to access only notepad.i need to prevent accidental close of this application.

Comment: There are better ways to do this. If you have 8.1, look into [Assigned Access](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/set-up-a-pc-as-a-kiosk-using-windows-81s-assigned-access/). Earlier versions of Windows also support different forms of "kiosk" modes.

Comment: Users are login with their domain account, we are not supposed to create a local user account by compromising security policies . We have applied other AD polices for admin users as well.
The only way what i found by thinking from the current situation is this script :(